# In ggplot2 how to show emmeans contrast significant p values in plot edited

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have been copying my boxplot graphs to word and manually putting in the significant p-values. When I use the recommended code  **stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, label.y = c(85, 90, 95)**  I end up with numbers that are not accurate. What I am looking for is for a bracket with significant p=values from the last line of code  **emmeans(lmer2, pairwise ~ Year | transect)** from the results of emmeans contrasts. I have tried using the word contrasts instead of comparison

Here is the source code I ran

https://rpubs.com/mberry1/713185

example code

```
plots     transect  Year Total
<chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 D11_NORTH        1     1   46 
2 D11_SOUTH        1     1   56.
3 R27_NORTH        1     1   34 
4 R27_SOUTH        1     1   38 
5 R28_NORTH        1     1   50 
6 R28_SOUTH        1     1   34 
7 D13_NORTH        2     1   60 
8 D13_SOUTH        2     1   10 

glm_test$year <- factor(glm_test$year,
                    levels = c(1, 2, 3),
                    labels = c("2018", "2019", "2020"))


glm_test$transect <- factor(glm_test$transect,
                        levels = c(1, 2,3),
                        labels = c("Lower Meadow", "Middle Meadow", "Upper 
Meadow"))
summary(glm_test)
```

#run the linear model with cover as dependent variable, year as
#independent var. for the plot by stating + (1| plot), This makes it a #repeated measures

```
lmer2 <- lmer(cover ~ as.factor(year) * as.factor(transect) + (1|plot), 
          data = glm_test)
anova(lmer2)
```

#post Hoc comparisons

```
emmeans(lmer2, list(pairwise ~ year), adjust = "tukey")
```

#If there was an interaction your code would be this

```
emmeans(lmer2, pairwise ~ year | transect)
```

Results of Contrasts for transect = Upper Meadow:

|contrast    |  estimate|  SE df| t.ratio| p.value|
| ---------- | -------- | ----- | ------ | ------ |
|2018 - 2019 |  27.500  |7.15 38|  3.848 | 0.0013 |
|2018 - 2020 |  20.000  |7.15 38|  2.798 | 0.0214 |
|2019 - 2020 |  -7.500  |7.15 38| -1.049 | 0.5509 |
Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates

#Visulize data

```
ggboxplot(glm_test, x = "year", y = "cover", title = "Total % Cover of 
Upland 
Species Across All Years",
      ylab = " % Cover UPL Species",
      color = "transect", ggtheme = theme_gray(base_size = 14))+
stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, label.y = c(85, 90, 95))+
stat_compare_means(label.y = 110)
```

[image]

The above boxplot does not make sense to me, I am looking for the significant p-values in the emmenas contrast above. The below boxplot is one I placed p-values in by hand in word

[image]

Comment: I dunno, but it looks to me that you might have Tukey-adjusted P values in the first plot and unadjusted ones in the second.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I did not realize that my example code did not make it in. I have edited it and both are Tukey-adj p. The first graph is just displaying the middle meadow. In the second graph, I put in the p-values from the results of the interaction from the Tukey post hoc.

Comment: OK. Well I don't use stat_compare_means so can't help. With so many means, I think this plot is messy if you show all the P values, and confusing if you only show some. Maybe your best bet is to do it manually. You might consider pwpp() or pwpm() in emmeans package for displaying P values

Comment: Thanks! I just ended doing it manually

Comment: If I had to guess, it'd be that your software is displaying comparisons of the marginal means of the years